# index.d.ts type definitions being ignored by tsc when compiling

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, tsc

I have an Express app built in TypeScript that I'm attempting to compile using the [`tsc`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) CLI tool.

An issue that I'm facing, however, is that `tsc` seems to ignore the `index.d.ts` file that I've created and used to mutate the Express `Request` object.

This is my `index.d.ts` file:

```
declare global{
    namespace Express{
        export interface Request{
            foo: string;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to do stuff like this inside my controller's requests without TypeScript spitting out a `does not exist` error:

```
export const example = async (req: Request) => {
    const { foo } = req;
    // Outputs "bar". This works completely fine in development.
    console.log(foo);
};
```

I'm running the following command to build my app:

```
tsc ./Main.ts --outdir build
```

Which results in the following error multiple times across every controller that uses it:

```
error TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an empty export to your index.d.ts file:

```
export {};

declare global{
    namespace Express{
        export interface Request{
            foo: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't work. It's already declared as a module file since I'm using `import` at the top.

Comment: But it helped in my case, so the suggestion is not completely invalid.